# Reload part of the page Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with a td that updates when i press a button `.pauseDocker`

When It's paused I'm reloading the page. Surely there's a smarter way to just refresh just part of the page in this case the table.

```
$(document).on('click','.pauseDocker' ,function(){
    var buttonClicked = $(this);
    var containerName = $(this).attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/container/pause',
        data: {containerName: containerName},
        success: function () {

            location.reload();
        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please can you describe your problem or what your specific concern with your code is? "Please improve my code" questions are not specific enough for SO.

Comment: What is the refresh supposed to do anyway? (I know it reloads the page but why are you doing that)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first parameter of the success callback and this will contain data from the response of your server. Use that to retrieve the changed data and update client side accordingly

Comment: How come these few lines of string posses the capability of becoming a full fledged answer,that's what the comment section are for

Comment: @AL-zami because i'm answering his question on how to do it without reloading the page